# Necessary condition for $\oint_C Pdx + Q dy = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $P, Q$ have continuous partial derivatives in simply connected region $R$ enclosed by the curve $C$. Is $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ should necessarily hold in every point for $\oint_C Pdx + Q dy = 0$. There is a problem that claims that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ for every point in the region. Wouldn't this integral $\displaystyle \iint_S \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right)dxdy $ be equal to zero if the term $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ were symmetric in region?

For example:- if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = x$ and the surface is a rectangle $x = -a $ to $x = a$ and $y = 0$ to $y=b$

[image]

Comment: The proof you've supplied is showing that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ at every point $P$ in $R$ is a necessary condition for the integral around *every* closed curve in $R$ is 0.

Comment: yes that's what I mean (I find it hard to swallow)... if they are equal then it is sufficient for that closed loop integral to be zero. Would't what I supplied as an example be zero even they are not equal.

Comment: It could happen (if they are not equal) that an integral around come closed loop is zero, but an integral around another closed loop is not zero.

Comment: Notice the example you've given is not a counterexample, because there are closed paths in the rectangle that do not integrate to 0.  You've chosen a specific path, but the proof is trying to show that a necessary condition is that *all* closed paths integrate to 0.

Comment: @GEdgar does every loop include that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ all loops?

Comment: @Jared maybe I terribly misunderstood the problem. :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your trouble is in understanding the statement of the theorem.  I will state it as clearly as I can.

> A necessary condition that $\oint_C Pdx+Qdy=0$ for all closed paths $C$ in a simply connected region $\mathcal{R}$ is that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ at all points in $\mathcal{R}$.  In other words, if $\oint_C Pdx+Qdy=0$ for all closed paths $C$ in a simply connected region $\mathcal{R}$, then $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ at all points in $\mathcal{R}$.

I think you've interpreted the statement as "If $\oint_C Pdx+Qdy=0$ for some closed path $C$, then $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ at all points in the region $\mathcal{R}$ bounded by $C$."  The difference in these two statements is subtle, but the first one is true, while you've shown in your example that the second one is false.

The point is, as you've shown in your example, that we can find a simply connected region $\mathcal{R}$ and a *specific* closed curve $C$ in $\mathcal{R}$ such that $\oint_C Pdx+Qdy=0$, with $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\ne\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ at all points in $\mathcal{R}$.  However, in all of these cases, it will be possible to find another closed path $C'$ in $\mathcal{R}$ such that $\oint_{C'} Pdx+Qdy\ne0$.

As shown in the proof, this follows from the continuity of the partial derivatives and Green's theorem.  Once we have some point in $\mathcal{R}$ where $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}>0$, then we must have some neighborhood where $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}>0$ (by continuity).  Integrating over this neighborhood gives a positive line integral (by Green's theorem), contradicting the hypotheses.